# How to extract MethodInfo.Invoke parameters from an object maybe implementing IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, system.reflection, methodinfo

Using reflection, I am trying to invoke Linq method IEnumerable.FirstOrDefault() on an object that is expected to be IEnumerable of some type, and return the result object.

I have the following classes:

```
class MyClass : IEnumerable<MyOtherClass>
{
    public IEnumerator<MyOtherClass> GetEnumerator() { yield return new MyOtherClass(); }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}

class MyOtherClass { }
```

This is how I attempted to invoke the method and return the result:

```
object GetFirstItemFromObject(object objectThatIsExpectedToImplementIEnumerableT) 
{
    Type genericType = 
        objectThatIsExpectedToImplementIEnumerableT
        .GetType()
        .GetInterfaces()
        .Where(@interface => @interface.Name == "IEnumerable`1")
        .FirstOrDefault()
        ?.GenericTypeArguments
        ?.First()
        ?? throw new ArgumentException("Object does not implement IEnumerable<T>.");

    var methodInfo = 
        typeof(Enumerable)
        .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
        .Where(methodInfo1 => methodInfo1.Name == "FirstOrDefault")
        .Select(method => method.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { genericType }))
        .FirstOrDefault()
        ?? throw new ArgumentException("Object does not have method member FirstOrDefault.");

    return methodInfo.Invoke(objectThatIsExpectedToImplementIEnumerableT, new object[] { });
}
```

I expected that supplying a new `MyClass` to this method would return a new `MyOtherClass`, but it fails because `methodInfo.Invoke` expects a single object in the parameter array.

`System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: 'Parameter count mismatch.'`

I do not know what to supply to this method, or understand what I am supplying, or why I should have to supply it at all.

If I supply *some* type, I get the following exception:

`` System.ArgumentException: 'Object of type 'System.RuntimeType' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyNamespace.MyOtherClass]'.' ``

Other threads seem not to address the question of a `MethodInfo`'s invocation, or presume the type to supply to `MakeGenericMethod` is available at design time, or else give `MethodInfo.Invoke`'s parameter array as null or empty.

I would welcome any help in understanding this problem and, assuming my code for finding the generic type to supply as type arguments to `MakeGenericMethod` is at least functionally correct, what I should supply to `methodInfo.Invoke`, and why?

`return methodInfo.Invoke(objectThatIsExpectedToImplementIEnumerableT, new object[] {  ???  });`

Comment: why not simply try to  cast the object to IEnumerable<T>

Comment: I fell into the habit of using reflection while working through a list of cases where reflection was required. I'd still like to understand the expected value when using reflection, though, if only to better understand System.Reflection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FirstOrDefault is an Extension method, you need to pass `this` as an arg

```
return methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] {objectThatIsExpectedToImplementIEnumerableT });
```

Comment: First parameter should be `null`, as extension methods are `static`

Comment: Thank you, and to @Charlieface, for explaining this. I was missing that it was an extension method, and that what was required was the reference. I was labouring under the the assumption this would be a type, for some reason.

Comment: @Charlieface although it works fine with the useless first arg

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't, because there is a specific allowance for an object of the same type. I said it *should* be `null` to show that it's unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

You don't need reflection at all for that. `IEnumerable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable`, and you can get `IEnumerable<object>` from `IEnumerable` using `Cast<T>()`:

```
object GetFirstItemFromObject(object objectThatIsExpectedToImplementIEnumerableT) 
{
    var enumerableObject = (IEnumerable)objectThatIsExpectedToImplementIEnumerableT;
    return enumerableObject.Cast<object>().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Ha ha - that'll suit me for tonight! Thank you so much for pointing this out, though I had to do a bit of digging while I was misguidedly reflecting and am still invested in the question.